# Changing notebook directory leads to an error in loading extensions

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook

I'm running an IPython notebook through Django's `shell_plus` with the following command:

```
sudo ./manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

I'm not entirel sure how it works, but `./manage.py shell_plus` knows to look for additional settings in django's `settings.py` file, where I have the following IPython arguments:

```
IPYTHON_ARGUMENTS = [
    '--ext', 'django_extensions.management.notebook_extension',
    '--profile=mitchell',
    '--port=8889',
    '--notebook-dir=/home/rootadmin/server/',
    '--certfile=/ssl/fullchain.pem',
    '--keyfile=/ssl/privkey.pem',
    '--ip=*',
    '--no-browser',
    '--no-mathjax',
]
```

So far this all works as intended. It runs a notebook server, that I can access and it serves any notebook file within the `notebook-dir`, which is the same directory from which I run the `./manage.py shell_plus --notebook` command. I can execute code, and have access to my django models.

However, this is my general home directory and I don't want all my notebooks in this directory. I made a new directory, from which I want to serve my notebooks. I change my `notebook-dir` accordingly.

```
    '--notebook-dir=/home/rootadmin/server/jupyter_directory',
```

Then, if I run the notebook, it initially appears to work: I can access it online, and it shows me the notebooks within the `jupyter_directory`, however, when I try to run any code that required my django models, it no longer works, saying that these models are undefined. In the terminal, where I started the notebook I see the following error:

```
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Error in loading extension: django_extensions.management.notebook_extension
Check your config files in /home/rootadmin/.ipython/profile_mitchell
```

I don't know what to check for. I'm assuming the error is because it's trying to import from a wrong location now. How can I serve directory A, and import from directory B?